# Non verbose solution to make a class member variable optional based on the type of template?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

I want the class member variable `only_if_int` to be defined only if the class is instantiated with the template type int. I have a working solution, but it is too verbose.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T, typename Enable = void>
class MyClass;

template<typename T>
class MyClass<T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<T, int>::value>>{
   public:
      int common;
      int only_if_int;

      MyClass()
      {
         common = 0;
         only_if_int = 0;
      }

      void alter_values()
      {
         common++;
         only_if_int++;
      }
};

template<typename T>
class MyClass<T, std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same<T, int>::value>>{
   public:
      int common;
      MyClass()
      {
         common = 0;
      }

      void alter_values()
      {
         common++;
      }
};

int main()
{
   MyClass<int>  int_class;
   MyClass<float>  float_class;
   int_class.alter_values();
   float_class.alter_values();

   std::cout<<"\n int_class "<<int_class.common<<"  "<<int_class.only_if_int;
   std::cout<<"\n int_class "<<float_class.common<<"  ";

   return 0;
}
```

In the above code, the templated class `MyClass`  is defined twice(too much code duplicate). For eg: alter_values function is written twice. Is there a less verbose way, maybe with the help of `constexpr std::is_same<T, int>` or a different C++ feature to do the same thing?

Comment: This is more than just an extra class member. All the methods have to change too. Although there are some simpler ways to add class members, that won't be sufficient here.

Comment: @JeJo I am fine till c++14

Comment: If you can't use c++17, then you can't use `if constexpr`. Without that, specializing the entire class is about as clean as you can get. (maybe inheriting from a base class will help).

Comment: Sorry I am actually fine till c++17

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to have a type that contains an `int` member only if it's instantiated with `int`, like this:

```
template<typename>
struct OnlyInt {};

template<>
struct OnlyInt<int> {
    int only_if_int;
};
```

Then `MyClass` can just inherit from this type:

```
template<typename T>
class MyClass : public OnlyInt<T> {
    public:
      int common;
      // ... contains only_if_int if T == int      
};
```

Now all uses of `only_if_int` will need to be wrapped in an `if constexpr`, and you have to use `this->` to indicate that the member is from a base class. So for example:

```
only_if_int = 0;
```

becomes:

```
if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, int>)
    this->only_if_int = 0;
```

etc.

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/fosW65).